# NSString remains in memory

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsstring

I have been converting the entered password into `NSString`.

```
NSString * tempStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: [[DummyEnc sharedInstance] decDummy] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
...
...

tempStr = nil
```

`NSString` is required because `tempStr` handles other logic.

But there is a problem that `tempStr` remains in memory, how do I fix it?

Is there a way I would like to use it as an `NSString`?

Comment: Why do you mean by "`tempStr` remains in memory"? Why is it a problem? Why do you care if it "remains in memory"?

Comment: `tempStr` is  data such as user password. `tempStr = @ "000000", tempStr = nil` is as soon as `tempStr` is used for the required purpose. I thought that this would remove the value of `tempStr` from memory, but there is a problem that the value of `tempStr` is exposed when memory is dumped from the jailbroken phone. So I want to know what characteristics of NSString cause this problem. I also want to know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is normal. Many NSStrings get special memory management in Objective-C such that they are not released like normal objects when their retain count goes to zero. In effect, they are leaked *deliberately*.

This is a behind-the-scenes implementation detail and you typically wouldn't worry about it (or even know about it).

If this is a security problem for you (because the string shows up in a memory dump), store the string in some other way, e.g. wrapped up as an NSData.

Comment: Thank you for your good answer. I know I should refrain from using `NSString` for security reasons, but I want to use `strings`. If `NSString's` variables are intentionally in memory to be handled specially in memory management, what happens if I treat `tempStr` as `NSMutableString`?
I'm not in a situation where I can test this (my jailbreak phone is broken). I will ask again.

Comment: Yes, you could try NSMutableString and see; that's a good idea.

Comment: If you use an `NSMutableString`, I suggest that you replace the characters one at a time or something like that. If you attempt to use `replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` with a range that covers the whole string, there's an excellent chance that the implementation will just free its underlying storage and share the storage with the new string in a copy-on-write scheme or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for matt and Ken. It was a good opportunity to find out that NSString is special in memory management.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to release the memory of `tempStr` in **ARC**, just forget about it, the modern llvm compiler handler it for you automatically.

If you want to release the memory right now after finishing using it, maybe you need specify a `-fno-objc-arc` flag for that source file, then you could use `[tempStr release]` or `[tempStr autorelease]` to release it.

Have a nice try!

Comment: I do not think it's a simple release issue.  I used `tempStr` and then set a random value and assigned `nil`. Anyway, thanks for your reply.